# create a remote pc cheaply

Tags: remote

Problem: i have a high end gaming PC and a laptop. I work mostly on my laptop in my room since the PC is kept in hall due to some restriction. In a few days i am going to have to let go of my laptop, hence am looking for a cheap way to create a remote setup to substitute for my laptop utilizing the full power of my PC and providing a interface with least bit of latency.

I already have a spare monitor, keyboard, ups etc. All i need is a processing component which will connect to my PC over LAN WiFi (internet is unreliable). Am considering buying a raspberry pi for this job.

Oh and usage wise i would be running heavy programming tools to generous web browsing and media playing etc.

Comment: But what would you connect to the remote desktop via?

Comment: Have you thought about wireless HDMI? This way you wouldn't need any additional computer at all.

Comment: You're going to be way, way, way better off connecting the peripherals directly to the PC somehow, either wirelessly or with cables.

Comment: Not sure I agree with @goldilocks on the peripherals. It's definitely going to easier to connect them directly to the PC, but there are a couple of USB over IP solutions for the Pi, such as [USB/IP](http://usbip.sourceforge.net/) and [VirtualHere](https://www.virtualhere.com/).

Comment: I've edited your question slightly to remove "other ideas", since that is off-topic here (except for in, inevitably, comments) -- for that you might try our sibling site [Hardware Recommendations](http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).  @goobering Looks good, although if within bluetooth or RF range that (direct wireless) would still probably be better.  The former much more so than the latter I think.

Comment: @nsilent22 thanks for that new piece of info, something interesting for me to check out :). Can you suggest some good ones, i not able to find generic ones which work with PCs at the moment (just saw an article about microsoft's latest wireless HDMI though)

Comment: @goldilocks the rooms are far off so wired and bluetooth based solutions are out of question

Comment: Well, I've not used any of the devices yet, but quick googling lead me to https://airtame.com/download which seems to work on all platforms I'm interested in.

Comment: @nsilent22 thanks for that, found a few others too. But the pricing is prohibitive. Original goal was to have a cheap alternative to setup a terminal to my gaming pc.

Comment: Well, I have one Pi that I use sometimes for playing HD videos (my laptop is pretty old). So if you'd like to give Pi a try you can use x11vnc/vncviewer tandem setup. This way you'll run really simple X server on your Pi only for running vncviewer. This is not a solution for streaming video or gaming, but for doing work (e.g text editors) it shall be sufficient.